# How php iterator class works ? (Iterate through zend table row set)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have object which contains 100 records. I want to iterate through it and delete all the data in the object.

How can I do this in PHP iterator class ?

(Object is ZEND table row set object)

(Here delete means we are just making `delete_flag` in the database to 1. Data won't be deleted physically from the database.)

Eg:

```
$zendTableRowSetObject->list[0]->delete_flag = 1
$zendTableRowSetObject->list[2]->delete_flag = 1
$zendTableRowSetObject->list[3]->delete_flag = 1

$zendTableRowSetObject->save();
```

->save() is the Zend function, this will update the object which used to calls this method.

(Other than this any other method http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

(Without using foreach loop is there any way to do it ?)

Give me some examples .

Here is my iterator class

```
class PersonListIter implements Iterator
{
     protected $_PersonList;

    /**
     * Index of current entries
     * It's used for iterator
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $_entryIndex = 0;

    /**
     * Entries data sets
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_entries;

    /*
     * Initialization of data. 
     * 
     * @params  Zend_Db_Table_Rowset    $list   Row Object
     * @return  null
     */    
    public function __construct ( $list )
    {
        $this->_PersonList = $list;
        $this->_entryIndex = 0;
        $this->_entries = $list->getCount();
    }

    /*
     * Iterator interface method to rewind index
     * @return  null
     */     
    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->_entryIndex = 0;
    }

    /*
     * Iterator interface method to return Current entry
     * @return  Zend_Db_Table_Row   Current Entry
     */         
    public function current()
    {
        return $this->_PersonList->getElement($this->_entryIndex);
    }

    /*
     * Iterator interface method to return index of current entry
     * @return  int     Current Entry Index
     */     
    public function key()
    {
        return $this->_entryIndex;
    }

    /*
     * Iterator interface method to set the next index
     * @return  null
     */      
    public function next()
    {
        $this->_entryIndex += 1;
    }

    /*
     * Iterator interface method to validate the current index
     * @return  enum    0/1 
     */      
    public function valid()
    {
        return (0 <= $this->_entryIndex && $this->_entryIndex < $this->entries)?1:0;
    }

} // class PersonListIter
```

$zendTableRowSetObject is the PersonList object in the iterator class

Comment: If you want to delete all the data in the object, why not just delete the object?

Comment: (Here delete means we are just making `delete_flag` in the database to 1. Data won't be deleted physically from the database.)

Comment: Why foreach is not good?

Comment: I didn't say it is not good. I am asking whether iterator can itself do some kind of looping ?

Comment: @Sahal. If you don't want foreach, you can use `iterator_apply` function. Additionally you could implement ArrayAccess interface, and use `unset` function to delete elements.

Comment: May be @Sahal is trying to understand how to use this iterator class?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.willfitch.com/the-iterator-pattern-oop-techniques-in-php.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete all of them at once, you have to iterate through (using foreach or while in conjunction with next()) to delete them.

While surfing I have found the following link which might interest you. This explains the use of implement iterator pattern in PHP in an nice way. >> http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Iterator/